# MySQL Error from AWS Python Lambda Client (2004 (HY000): Can't create TCP/IP socket (97))

Tags: python, mysql, aws-lambda

I'm writing a Python lambda and am struggling to resolve a MySQL error that only occurs when deployed in AWS. The code works fine on localhost without having to stub or mock the MySQL connections (I test it locally by commenting out the stubs and verifying that the real request matches what I see in the database).

I confirmed that the MySQL database has both network-level and user-/database-level IP whitelisting that features the correct IP addresses for both local development and deployed environments. I also confirmed that my lambda's security group does NOT block any outbound ports that would cause this behavior. Based on what I know currently, this leaves only one possibility, something going wrong in the code.

Is there anything in the context above or examples below that indicates a possible root cause?

```py
import mysql.connector


def lambda_handler(event, context=None):
    try:
        with mysql.connector.connect(
            host="database_host",
            user="database_username",
            password="database_password",
            database="database_name",
        ) as mydb:
            print("it worked!")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

```
{
  "errorMessage": "2004 (HY000): Can't create TCP/IP socket (97)",
  "errorType": "DatabaseError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/src/main.py\", line 70, in lambda_handler\n    raise e\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/src/main.py\", line 64, in lambda_handler\n    for record in data:\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/src/main.py\", line 82, in get_zander_data\n    host=db_hostname, user=db_username, password=db_password, database=db_name\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/mysql/connector/__init__.py\", line 264, in connect\n    return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py\", line 80, in __init__\n    self.connect(**kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/mysql/connector/abstracts.py\", line 966, in connect\n    self._open_connection()\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py\", line 219, in _open_connection\n    sqlstate=exc.sqlstate)\n"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the connection to work in a reduced test case after removing all other dependencies beyond the MySQL connection. I'm about to add the dependencies back in one at a time to identify which ones are to blame, but my current hypothesis is the AWS Systems Manager Param Store because I was also seeing `AccessDeniedException` in the log output, and that would explain this if there were a permissions issue with the parameter store.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing exact same error with yours. I'm wondering if you could share how you solved the problem. Thank you very much in advance. :)